# How do I use a add method for another class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, arraylist

I am trying to use an add method that is in another class so I can test my program but I am stuck on how to proceed.

In my `Apartment` class I have created an add method

```
public void addApartment(Apartment newApartment)
{
   House ApartmentEntry = new Apartment();
   ApartmentEntry= newApartment;
   ArrayList.add(ApartmentEntry);
}
```

In the `Company` class I am trying to use the method above to add an `Apartment` as in below example (in `Company`) :

```
addApartment(price, numberofbaths, numberofbedrooms, squarefeet);
```

Comment: The question is quiet confusing. can you make it more clear

Comment: Also your naming convention is very confusing.

Comment: I dont really get your question, but why do you create a new instance of an apartment and then instantly overwrite it with method argument? Are you tring to create a copy of an object and save it in a list or what?

Answer (score 1):

Since your `addApartment` method is not static, you have to create an instance of `Company to use it. Plus, you don't have an`addApartment`method taking several parameters, so I guess you wanted to use those for the constructor of`Apartment` :

```
Company company = new Company(args);
company.addApartment(new Apartment(price, numberofbaths, numberofbedrooms, squarefeet));
```

Answer (score 1):

okay, lets say you have an Apartment class with an contructor like this:

```
public class Apartment{

    public Apartment(int price, int numberOfBaths, int numberOfBedrooms, int squarefeet){
         this.price = prive;
         ...
    }
}
```

this is how you create a new Instance of Apartment:

```
Apartment newApartment = new Apartment(price, numberOfBaths, numberOfBedrooms, squarefeet);
```

knowing that, your addApartment method looks probably like that:

```
public void addApartment(int price, int numberOfBaths, int numberOfBedrooms, int squarefeet)
{
   House ApartmentEntry = new Apartment(price, numberOfBaths, numberOfBedrooms, squarefeet);
   ...
}
```

I dont know what you wanted to do with that ArrayList, but for sure you have to declare it first:

```
ArrayList<Apartment> list = new ArrayList<Apartment>();
list.add(newApartment);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are trying to add the `Apartment` to the `Company`?

The `Company` class should have the `addApartment(...)` method.

so the `Company` class would be like:

```
    public class Company{
        private ArrayList<Apartment> apartments;

        public Company(){
            apartments = new ArrayList<Apartment>();
        }

        public addApartment(Apartment apartment){
            this.apartments.add(apartment);
        }
    }
```

then you would simply:

```
Company company = new Company(args...);
company.addApartment(new Apartment(price, numberOfBaths, numberOfBedrooms, squarefeet));
```